# Adding numbers enclosed in characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to add numbers in excel which contain characters.

For example, I want to add

```
rs30/-
rs40/-
rs45/-
```

I want result as `rs115/-`

I tried

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(--A1:A3),--A1:A3))
```

but that gives zero.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MID` to extract the number text from the character string, then `VALUE` to convert that text to an actual numerical value, then add those using `SUM`, then use `&` to concatenate with the characters you want before and after the result.

Example:

```
="rs" & SUM(VALUE(MID(A1:A3,3,LEN(A1:A3)-4))) & "/-"
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Any idea without array formula?

Comment: Yes, but why? Before you ask for further input, you should read this: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: If you use `SUMPRODUCT` in place of `SUM` then you don't need "array entry" - of course it would be better if you had just numbers in A1:A3 - you can format the cells to display as "rs" etc but you would only need a simmple SUM function to sum them

Comment: It is not working when I add a "." after Rs. How I calculate rs.30/- +  rs.40/- +rs.45/-.? please....

Comment: First please read this: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Then, I suggest you try to understand the formula I suggested, and adapt it to your situation. We'll be happy to help if you tell us what specific problem you are running into — and show some appreciation for the help already given.

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer to strip out `rs` and `/-` (with Find & Select), then format as:

```
"rs"0"/-"
```