# Stripping numbers from text for addition

Tags: excel

While adding Rs.30/-+Rs.40/-+Rs.50/-The following formula is not working, but if I write "Rs" instead of "Rs." it is working fine.

```
="Rs." & SUM(VALUE(MID(A1:A3,3,LEN(A1:A3)-4))) & "/-"
```

Comment: Not really much to go on but could it have something to do with `.40.` having a period as both a prefix and a suffix? Perhaps expanding your description would shed some light. Sample data (as on the worksheet, not clumped together in a narrative) and expected results would also help.

Comment: sorry! it is not Rs.40./- but Rs.40/-. The result should be Rs.120/-

Comment: This is an almost exact duplicate of your own previous question: [Adding numbers enclosed in characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850006/adding-numbers-enclosed-in-characters)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you are starting with `Rs.` then you have a starting position (e.g. *4*). Try looking for the position of the slash and subtracting the known starting position.

[image: Rs additions]

The *array formula* in A4 is,

```
="Rs." & SUM(VALUE(MID(A1:A3,4, FIND("/", A1:A3)-4)))&"/-"
```

Finalize with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

Comment: Nice. really appreciable.